# Regex to print implementing interfaces from a Java source file

Tags: regex, grep

I have a bunch of java source files and want to list the interfaces implemented by each class in the sources.

The best case is when a class is declared in one line

```
class MyClass implements MyInterfaceA, MyInterfaceB {
```

However, there are classes that are declared in multiple lines

```
class SomeClass 
     implements
        InterfaceC,
        InterfaceD
        {
```

So, basically, if I can have a regex that can capture everything between the first `implements` string literal and the first occurrence of character `{`, I have the names of implementing interfaces.

For the last hour or so, I've been tinkering with several tools like grep, pcregrep, sed and awk and finally arrived at one command that seems to work.

```
pcregrep -M 'class[\s\S]*implements'
```

As you can see, I am trying to output everything between the words `class` and `implements` and the command outputs the lines

```
class SomeClass 
     implements
```

When I modify the same expression to output everything between `implements` and `{`, it outputs much more than I require, perhaps because there are so many `{` in the file and/or because `{` is a special character.

How do I output just the text between the first `implements` and the first `{` after that?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU **grep**:

Sample `input.java` file:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterfaceA, MyInterfaceB {
}
class SomeClass 
     implements
        InterfaceC,
        InterfaceD
        {
}
```

---

The job:

```
my_interfaces=$(grep -Poz '\bimplements[[:space:]]*\K[^{]*(?=\{)' input.java | tr -s '\n' ' ')
echo "$my_interfaces"
```

The output:

```
MyInterfaceA, MyInterfaceB InterfaceC, InterfaceD
```